# Runnable JAR bad Encoding in hebrew

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, executable-jar, right-to-left

I created a java app that send email in Hebrew.

When I **run it via Eclipse, everything is fine**,

BUT,

When I **run it via The exported Runnable JAR file everything is not fine anymore!**

When I receive the message on outlook its perfect:

> מק"ט: 19 התקבל ב: 2014-09-16 בשעה: 13:00:24 שם הפרוייקט: שם מזמין
>   העבודה:

BUT, **When I receive the massage on Gmail, it’s all scrambled:**

> ×ž×§"×˜: 19 ×”×ª×§×‘×œ ×‘: 2014-09-16 ×‘×©×¢×”: 13:00:24 ×©×
>   ×”×¤×¨×•×™×™×§×˜: ×©× ×ž×–×ž×™×Ÿ ×”×¢×‘×•×“×”:

I tried to play with the browsers encoding settings, but no such luck, It’s now set to Unicode-UTF 8. My project in eclipse is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Is your email some text file which is read by your Java application before sending it? Do you run the standalone Java application from console? What operating system are you using?

Comment: the email is created from text that was typed to the app, its a type of form that the user fills, and I just send the data via mail after.   I run the runnable jar by double clicking on it , not console, and I use Win7 Pro x64.

Comment: You can check the charset used in your email (when it is received by Gmail) reading the [message headers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en) Try to find something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`. If the charset is not UTF-8 there must be something wrong with your Java application (perhaps using some default charset instead of UTF-8)

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;    charset=UTF-8"><title>דואר Meimad MTVS Studios</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="application-name" content="דואר Meimad MTVS Studios">    ,   its weird , the charset is UTF-8 , but it should be ISO-8859-1 , that's how I output it from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got it to work,

used this code:

```
// -- Create a new message --
final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

// -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
}

msg.setSubject(title, "utf-8");
msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
  try {
mbp1.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
new ByteArrayDataSource(message.toString(), "text/html")));
      } catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 mbp1.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\""); 
 mbp1.setContent( message, "text/html; charset=utf-8" ); 
 mbp1.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");

// create the second message part
MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();

// attach the file to the message
try {
mbp2.attachFile(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
msg.setContent(mp, "text/html");
```